# Can I load and save my Minecraft maps to My Dropbox?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to setup Minecraft so that the maps are loaded and saved from a different folder (like my Dropbox folder)?

Where are they stored by default?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You would need *soft links* to do that.

Create a soft link from your minecraft savegame folder to inside the Dropbox folder.

However, it will be quite suboptimal. Minecraft stores save games in many, *many small* files and Dropbox does *not* support folder-wide rollbacks.

What I would use instead is a source control versioning system.

#### First time setup

1. [Learn the basics of Mercurial](http://hginit.com/)
2. Get Mercurial for your operative system

   - If you use a modern operative system, use your distribution's package manager.
   - For other operative systems, [download mercurial here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).
3. Run `hg init` on your save folder
4. Run `hg add; hg commit` to save the state of your game.

#### Backing up

1. Play the game normally.
2. When you close the game, run `hg commit` again to save the state of your game. Give a meaningful commit message (e.g. "got my first iron pickaxe!")

This, except maybe for the commit message, should be easily automated with batch files. Here's a very simple bash script for Ubuntu:

```
java -jar minecraft.jar
cd ~/.minecraft/
hg commit -m `zenity --entry --title Minecraft --text Announce your deeds!`
```

#### Going "back in time"

1. Notice your save file is corrupted.
2. - If you did commit last time you played, run `hg rollback` to undo the last commit and restore the save game to your previous save state.
   - If you did *not* commit last time you played, run `hg revert` to restore the save games to your last commit.
3. Be glad you bothered and keep on playing.

#### Dropbox backup

While we are scripting, we might as well have a *single file copy* of your game files to be put on Dropbox.

```
java -jar minecraft.jar
cd ~/.minecraft/
hg commit -m `zenity --entry --title Minecraft --text Announce your deeds!`
zip -r ~/Dropbox/Minecraft/savefile.zip .
```

This makes for a much more Dropbox-friendly solution -- just be aware you are backing up the repository, not just the game files. If you want just the latter:

```
java -jar minecraft.jar
cd ~/.minecraft/
hg commit -m `zenity --entry --title Minecraft --text Announce your deeds!`
hg archive zip ~/Dropbox/Minecraft/savefile.zip
```

#### Remote hosting

If you want to keep game files up to date between different machines, it is trivial to do so - even without Dropbox. You can have a remote copy of your repository for free at [these hosting solutions](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialHosting). Choose one that will not complain about your not using their service for a non-code project... [Intuxication](http://beta.intuxication.org/) for example.

Be very careful, however -- you want to avoid conflicts. Merging will *not* work, so you will need to always push after you play and always pull before you play. This is trivial to do if you are using a script:

```
hg pull #get remote changes 
java -jar minecraft.jar
cd ~/.minecraft/
hg commit -m `zenity --entry --title Minecraft --text Announce your deeds!`
hg push #push to remote server
```

Specific setup details vary based on your hosting solution.

Comment: Porting the above to your operative system is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: It's a little bit overkill for what I was looking for, but great info anyways, thanks!

Comment: @travis, it seems overwhelming because I did a lot thinking for you :) but Dropbox isn't going to save you the moment your save file goes belly up with a simple symlink I'm afraid.

Comment: It's not overwhelming, I use source control all the time, although I usually use SVN (I also use git, TFS, and VSS ***shudder*** at work). How would a save file go belly up from using a symlink though?

Comment: @travis It's not the symlink, it's not the versioning system -- it's the game that will occasionally junk your save file :(

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks! I'll probably stick with using a symlink for now, but I'll use your idea of a batch file and backup the saves into a zip in a separate folder.

Comment: Why recommend Mercurial instead of Git?

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I did it on Windows:

1. Backup your saves 
    (located in `%AppData%\.minecraft\saves\`)
2. Move your saves to a folder inside your Dropbox or Live Mesh or whatever file syncing service 
    (eg: `My Dropbox\Minecraft\saves\`)
3. Create a junction that points to your sync'd saves: 
    `mklink /J "%AppData%\.minecraft\saves" "Your Dropbox Folder\minecraft\saves"`

More info on [NTFS Junctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point), [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTEwNTIzMDk) (2GB, cross-platform, referral link), [Live Mesh](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh) (5GB, Windows/Mac only).

**Update:** Here's a handy batch file to backup your save games in a [zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) file before launching minecraft:

```
@echo off
echo "Backing up save files..."
"Your Path To 7zip\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r -mx7 -tzip "Your Dropbox Folder\minecraft\saves.zip" "%AppData%\.minecraft\saves"
minecraft.exe
```

Answer (score 4):

On the Mac, your worlds are stored in ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/. You can create an symbolic link at that location to wherever you'd like, Dropbox or otherwise, and Minecraft will follow that symlink to a different location.

Comment: So it sounds like you'd move the saves folder to Dropbox (or whatever) and then just command+option+drag the folder back ro its original location right?

http://www.apple.com/pro/tips/alias.html

Comment: Yep, that is exactly how you would do it.

Comment: hmm, when I did that minecraft shows all the slots as empty, is there a better way to create an alias (or symlink or junction) on the mac?

Comment: When I try to go there in Terminal:

$ cd saves

`-bash: cd: saves: Not a directory`

Comment: This worked:

`ln -s ~/Dropbox/minecraft/saves ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft/`

Comment: A command+option+drag doesn't create a symlink, it creates an *alias*. See [What's the difference between alias and link?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/whats-the-difference-between-alias-and-link) Importantly, Minecraft can't follow an alias, but it can follow a symlink.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Sugarsync](https://www.sugarsync.com/)?  It will allow you to sync specific folders on your computer as opposed to having to link everything through the dropbox folder.

Comment: Sounds cool, but sadly I'm too cheap to spend $5 a month on it :-)

Comment: Actually... they're hiding the free version that I was using when I tried it.  https://www.sugarsync.com/trialpay/ they're limiting it to 2 gb max (not an issue), and 2 computers only (possibly an issue), at least worth giving a try now